# Use/Update same ReadMe.md file in multiple repositories

Tags: git, bitbucket

I've more than 25 repositories in BitBucket. We are following same guidelines for all the repositories. It is a difficult task for me to update readme for all the repositories.

Is there any way to update the ReadMe file in all repositories whenever it is updated in one repository.

In another way, I can publish the guidelines in my website and simply add the link to the readme file. But I want to read the guideline document even in offline :)

Thanks in advance